# Continuity from above of measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm completely new to measure theory, and I'm looking at the following problem:

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathbb{R}$, such that $\mu((a,b]) < +\infty$ when $-\infty<a\leq b<+\infty$ that satisfies for some $F: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$
$$\mu((a,b]) = F(b)-F(a).\hspace{2cm}(*) $$
Then I need to show that such $F$ is **continuous from above**, that is

$$\forall\varepsilon>0\exists\delta>0: \,\,h\in(0,\delta)\implies|F(x_0+h)-F(x_0)|\leq \varepsilon. $$
I know from $(*)$ that for all $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and $h>0$ that
$$|F(x_0+h)-F(x_0)| = |\mu((x_0,x_0+h])|, $$
however I don't see exactly how I should bound that.

---

By the way, I have shown existence of $F$ satisfying $(*)$. It is the following
$$F(x) =\begin{cases}-\mu((x,0]) &\text{if } x<0\\\mu((0,x])&\text{if }x\geq 0\end{cases}$$
and it is unique up to addition of a constant.

Comment: Consider strictly decreasing sequences $h_n$ converging to $0$. Since $\mu$ is a measure, you know a bit about $\mu\left(\bigcup A_k\right)$ for sequences $(A_k)$ of nice (= $\mu$-measurable) sets.

Comment: @DanielFischer I know if $(A_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ is decreasing (i.e. $A_{k+1}\subset A_k$) then $\lim_{k\to\infty}\mu(A_k) = \mu\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty A_k\right)$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: That's what I was aiming at, but indirectly. Note, however, that you need $\mu(A_k) < \infty$ for some (and hence all but finitely many) $k$. What could a good choice for the $A_k$ be here?

Comment: Yep, $\mu(A_k)$ is assumed to be finite when $A_k$ is finite, so I left that out. I guess I could choose something like $A_k = (x_0,x_0+\frac1k]$. This converges to the empty set and hence the measure of it converges to zero, right?

Comment: Yes, you could choose those. Then you know $\mu(A_k) \to 0$. How can you use that to find $\delta$ for a given $\varepsilon$?

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't know :-(. I understand that as the interval shrinks, the measure shrinks (at least, eventually). But I do not understand how I can quantify this in terms of $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Given $\varepsilon > 0$, can you find a $k_\varepsilon$ such that ...?

Comment: I guess I'm really bad at $\varepsilon$-$\delta$. I know that $\lim_{k\to\infty} \mu((x_0,x_0+1/k]) = 0$, hence for each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $K$ s.t. $\mu((x_0,x_0+1/k])\leq \varepsilon$ when $k\geq K$, however I don't know what this $K$ is, only that it exists? Am I allowed to say that $\delta = 1/K$?

Comment: Right, without knowing $\mu$ (or $F$), you can't know what $K$ is, only that such a $K$ exists. But that's enough. You cannot say that $\delta = 1/K$ without argument, however. Which properties of $\mu$ can you use to show that indeed you can pick $\delta = 1/K$?

Comment: @DanielFischer It is downward continuous, which is what we used to deduce that its limit is $0$. However measures are also monotonic (i.e. $A\subset B\implies \mu(A)\leq\mu(B)$), is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, the monotonicity is what helps there.